# Best Practice - ASP.NET Combine all JavaScript output

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, typescript

I am curious as to what the best practice is to combine all JavaScript into one file.  I am using Visual Studio ASP.NET MVC 5 and TypeScript.  I also have jQuery and a bunch of plugins, as well as my own page specific JavaScript fies.

Visual Studio has an option under Build Options -> TypeScript Build to "Combine JavaScript output into file".

Does this combine only the JavaScript generated from the my TypeScript files, or will it also combine jQuery and the various plugins?

Is there any possibility for collisions (multiple .ts files having the same variable name), or does TypeScript natively avoid that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typescript build option (--out in tsc) will only concatenate the typescript within the project. You may run into issues with file ordering if you use this. Using CommonJS with browserify solves this issue, though the TypeScript project itself uses the --out option for building the typescript compiler. Nevertheless this will not concatenate your vendor library files like jQuery.

The best option is to use gulp or grunt as part of your build process to concatenate and uglify your compiled Typescript and Javascript.

You should not be using global variables and thus will not have variable collisions. Instead your code should use modules. This can be the traditional javascript module pattern which is equivalent to Typescript modules, or the AMD modules like Require.js or CommonJS modules which actually are better suited for concatenated code.

Comment: Thank you very much!  Would you suggest gulp or grunt?  Also, are there any resources you can recommend where I can go and learn about all the technologies you mentioned above?

Thanks!

Comment: Also, if my application is not a SPA, does combining doing any of this make sense?

Comment: Take a look at grunt and gulp. Go with whichever you feel more comfortable with. They do the same thing, just are configured in apposing paradigms. There are places where concatenating code does not pay off, but generally it does. If your code is very specific to individual pages, maybe you are better off only uglify it. Go to the browserfy, requirejs and systemjs pages and read up on them.